# Displaying branch name in terminal - unexpected output

Tags: git

I recently used a script I found online to display the current branch I am in. Worked like a charm.
I usually create a feature branch in more than one project, as is the case when I am refactoring a dependency and needs to update the client as well.
In any case, I created a branch in four different git repos this morning, all work fine, except one repo where in the terminal it is displaying:

```
@user folder (master|REBASE-i)
```

instead of the the branch name. The normal display in other repos is something like:

```
@user folder (branch name)
```

Any idea what that would mean?

Comment: are you using only CLI? it's strange that you're in interactive rebase without knowing it...

Comment: I know, maybe I was in a rebase in this repo and completely forgot about it. Or maybe I missed the warning when I created the new branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you're in the middle of an [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html), which means that the history is currently being rewritten to rewrite or re-order commits.

If you want to dismiss this behaviour, run `git rebase --abort`